# Trabalhando com Moeda (decimal)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde tive a necessidade de usar `decimal` para campo Moeda.

Como o padrão americano e diferente do brasileiro logo tive algumas dificuldades.

Encontrei alguns exemplos de como lidar com isso, mas não obtive muito sucesso. Alguém tem algum exemplo ou solução para este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No *Model*, uso assim:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Price", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Nas *Views*, [uso o pacote NuGet JQuery Masked Input](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.MaskedInput/), então é preciso adicionar uma `@section scripts` na sua View:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#Price').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$ ', allowNegative: false, thousands: '.', decimal: ',', affixesStay: false });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Aliás, também é bom informar ao `Web.config` sobre a cultura utilizada. Não é exatamente necessário para este caso, mas pode servir bem ao resto do sistema.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    ...
    <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
    ...
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```