# ASP.NET MVC: Problema no Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou passando um objeto que tem seguinte propriedade para a Action:

```
{
    ...
    Valor : "3500.00"
}
```

FinancaPessoalViewModel:

```
public class FinancaPessoalViewModel
{
    ...
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdicionarLancamento(FinancaPessoalViewModel financa)
{
    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    //The value '3500.00' is not valid for Valor.
    ...
}
```

Está vindo sempre 0 para a propriedade "Valor", ele não está consegundo fazer o binding. Como arrumar isso?

Comment: Se passar o valor como `3500,00` (com vírgula) funciona?

Comment: Isso é problema de cultura diferente, com certeza se passar ',' ao invés de ponto conforme dito pelo nosso amigo jbueno vai funcionar. E você pode contornar isso utilizando essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39762/30045)  =]

Comment: Ah sim, valeu pessoal! Era isso mesmo. Estava sem entender pois o C# só "entendi" decimal com ponto, e não com vírgula.